# How to use the PivotalTracker API with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pivotaltracker

I am trying to use the PivotalTracker API to get all the stories from an epic. I am very lost on where to begin. I looked at the samples, but they are using cURL, not python. I also stumbled upon the pytracker module but it is 4 years old and is obsolete as PivotalTracker has switched over from XML to JSON during that time. Again I'm very lost on where to start, but appreciate any guidance you have to offer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up installing the Requests module for Python and managed to make the cURL requests through that. Here is how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25797678/1536101

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pytracker wrapper library:  https://code.google.com/p/pytracker/

Or, you would directly use urllib to call Pivotal Tracker's restful APIs:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

Comment: Will pytracker still work? I thought it was too old as Pivotal Tracker has switched from XML to JSON