# How to use Requests Python module to make curl calls

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, python-requests, pivotaltracker

I need to use an API that makes cURL calls. API shown here: https://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api/rest/v5. I am coding in Python 2.7 and downloaded the Requests module to use for the cURL calls, however I'm not exactly sure how to do this. This is what I have so far:

```
import requests

username = 'my_username'
password = 'my_password'
url = 'https://www.pivotaltracker.com/n/projects/my_project_number'

r = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))
```

Now that I have the response r, what do I do with it to make the cURL calls in order to use the API functions, such as the GET /projects/{project_id}/epics/{epic_id} function. The cURL call for this function is:

```
export TOKEN='your Pivotal Tracker API token'
export PROJECT_ID=99

curl -X GET -H "X-TrackerToken: $TOKEN" "https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/projects/$PROJECT_ID/epics/4"
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

**EDIT** (thanks to @Rob Watts)
Now this is my code:

```
import requests

username = 'my_username'
password = 'my_password'
url = 'https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/me'

r = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))
response_json = r.json()
token = response_json['api_token']

project_id = 'my_project_id'
url = 'https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/projects/{}/epics/1'

r = requests.get(url.format(project_id), headers={'X-TrackerToken':token})

print r.text
```

But it still isn't working. This is the output:

```
{
  "code": "unfound_resource",
  "kind": "error",
  "error": "The object you tried to access could not be found.  It may have been removed by another user, you may be using the ID of another object type, or you may be trying to access a sub-resource at the wrong point in a tree."
}
```

But per the documentation, I expect something like this:

```
{
    "created_at": "2014-08-26T12:00:00Z",
    "description": "Identify the systems and eliminate the rebel scum.",
    "id": 1,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're using the right project id. Also, in general if a followup question can't fit in a comment you should ask a new question.

Comment: I checked and my project_id is correct. An interesting thing I tried was putting this url in the browser: https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/projects/my_project_id/epics/1 but this too returned the same error

Comment: Perhaps you don't have an epic with id 1. Use /services/v5/projects/my_project_id/epics to get existing epics.

Comment: ... D'OH I assumed they were just ordered numerically. Of course not. Thanks for all you help and catching my silly mistakes. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the first call you should make is to the '/me' endpoint, and then pull the API token from the response:

```
import requests

username = 'my_username'
password = 'my_password'
url = 'https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/me'

r = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))
response_json = r.json()
token = response_json['api_token']
```

You can get some other stuff besides your API token from that endpoint. Take a look at [the documentation for that endpoint](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api/rest/v5#Me) to see if there is anything else you will need.

Once you've gotten your API token, all the other calls will be fairly simple. For example:

```
project_id = 'your_project_id' # could get this from the previous response
r = requests.get('https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/projects/{}/epics/4'.format(project_id), headers={'X-TrackerToken':token})
```

I'll explain the parts of the cURL call they have for this example and how they translate:

```
export VARNAME
```

Set a variable for the cURL call to use. Where you see `$VARNAME` is where the variables are being used.

```
-X GET
```

I don't know why they include this. This just specifies to use a GET, which is the default for cURL. Using `requests.get` takes care of this. However, for ones that have `-X POST`, you'd use `requests.post`, etc.

```
-H "X-TrackerToken: $TOKEN"
```

This specifies a header. For Requests, we use the `headers` keyword argument - `headers={key:value}`. In this specific example, we have `headers={'X-TrackerToken':token}`.

```
"https://..."
```

The url. That goes in as the first argument. Variables (like `$PROJECT_ID` in your example) can be inserted using the `format` method of strings.

Comment: thanks for the answer. If you don't mind I'd like to know how exactly you converted that, like how you knew to put the token into a header, and not the project id for instance.

Comment: VERY helpful! Thanks so much. I have been looking for that translation for a few hours now, so thanks again. Last question, the keys for the key:value pairs are just the string before the ':'? So for -H "X-TrackerToken: $TOKEN" it would be 'X-TrackerToken'

Comment: For that, "X-TrackerToken" is the key, and the token is the value. I'm guessing that it won't actually be "TOKEN".

Comment: Sorry, one more question. How do I incorporate the authentication part as well? Should i just make two different GET requests? Or do I put the auth param in the same GET call like this: r = requests.get(url.format(project_id), auth=(username, password), headers={'X-TrackerToken':token})

Comment: It looks like you need to get the token from a call to '/services/v5/me' and then use that. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see how that is done, better to get that info using the /me call then to hardcode it in. However I'm still getting an error with my updated code above. Any ideas?